# Connection string for using entity in class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class library that I am using as a DAL for a project.

I have the following connection string in my app.config for the main app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source='C:\temp\data.sdf'"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>


public class Container : ObjectContext
{
    public Container()
        : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
    }
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyEntities"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

I am receiving and exception when connecting using the connectionstring:

Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

What do I need to add to the connection string to access the sqlce database?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to remove single-quotes here: `'C:\temp\data.sdf'` because samples I've seen throughout the internet shows it without quotes..